# Who is driving Red Dwarf?

Tags: red-dwarf

I don't know if this has been explained in series 11 and I must have missed it.

***Who is driving Red Dwarf now that Holly has disappeared?***

Comment: No evidence to make this an answer, but I'd assume they just point Red Dwarf at Earth and off they go, maybe Kryten needs to make minor course corrections along the way every couple of millenia, but nothing worthy of mention during an episode.

Comment: @colmde the early seasons were quite explicit on how difficult the task of navigating the ship was and that's why holly had so high an IQ (degraded over time because he went nuts from all the time alone).

Answer (score 5):

On Red Dwarf, although Holly can control the flight of the ship, all commands go via the Navicomp (Fitted to both Red Dwarf and all Starbug class ships). Starbug is capable of flying itself without Holly, and this implies that the Navicomp is capable of autonomous flight.

So to answer your question, it is the Navicomp.

Answer (score 4):

"Holly, plot a course for Fiji. Look out Earth, the slime's coming home!"

Lister has it right. Despite Holly's implied lack of intelligence the AI is responsible for piloting the ship. The other members of the crew frequently ask him/her what is happening and on multiple occasions lay the blame on Holly for any navigational or piloting errors.

Answer (score 1):

The Navicomp is the Navigation Computer and controls the flight of Red Dwarf.

The Navicomp is a type of computer, found aboard both Red Dwarf and Starbug, which controls flight operations.

It can control the ship on autopilot, though this was said previously to be done by Holly in "Backwards".

Answer (score -3):

I don't know that anyone is. I vaguely recall a joke about Holly arguing with the auto-pilot, but only vaguely.

Otherwise, maybe noone is and the vessel is just randomly barelling through space with no destination or intent just like it has for over 3 million years. Possibly a metaphor for destiny, life or the crew's general aimlessness. Or even for the show itself!

Alarmingly, does this make the JMC Red Dwarf a space hulk?

Comment: If you don't know, why are you answering?